# Fixed Header in HTML 5 Web App Flickers (Android)

Tags: android, web, header, fixed

so I have a web app that has a fixed header in it. As the user scrolls down the page, at the very top of the page the background (content the user scrolls down) flickers at random intervals.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it myself by adding

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

to the header and content div. Now if only stackoverflow would let me accept this as an answer.